# How to Cut out RectF From a Bitmap?

Tags: android

I want to make a walking sprite animation. I have a one `bitmap` with all 31 sprite frames. I draw one frame on canvas `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, Rect src, RectF dst, paint)`. The problem is `Rect src` coordinates are `int` and when I divide `bitmap.getWidth()` by 31 to set a frame coordinates I get `float`. Is there a way to cut out `RectF` from a `bitmap`.

I can cut out `Rect` and scale it, but I would prefer the first option.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to cut out and store a piece of bitmap into memory with a float size. One can  draw on float coordinates because it is possible to anti-alias the float edges on canvas.

So the solution I believe is to make your sprite sheet width = 31 x sprite_width, on the frist place, so that your cuts are a prefect match.

Comment: They are a prefect match, but when I rescale bitmap to fit different screen resolution cuts mix sprite frames. I want to rescale bitmap once in constructor, not always while drawing.

Comment: Yes, one can rescale it in onSizeChange also. I am doing the same and it does work for me providing that sprites have a bit of empty space, i.e. transparent pixels, between themselves, so that the cut does not have to be pixel perfect. Otherwise you would have to employ more mathematics and conditions when scaling your sprite-sheet.